# JSON-friendly database?

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, json, nosql

I have a pure jQuery app that keeps it's objects in JSON format and provides client-side editing. I want to persist the JSON to a database, but everything seems like overkill (like object mapping in C#). I am close to settling on storing the whole JSON string into a single column of a database. I was hoping there was more of an elegant, creative approach like a jQuery/JSON/database framework out there, but couldn't find anything (maybe NoSql can be of use?).

Any suggestions or advise on how to persisting JSON to a database using as less server code as possible?

Comment: Do you need to query on the attributes of your persisted objects? Need to sort results by one or more of those attributes? Are there any dependencies that require referential integrity/FK constraints?  Do you have any need to enforce uniqueness?  Need to do any aggregations? Or do you simply want to store the object as a key-value item and retrieve it based on its key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) due to it's JSON style documents.

It also has [plenty of drivers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers), so I wouldn't see it being an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's ok to use a server side technology, your description wasn't real clear for me.

The first thing that comes to mind for your needs is MongoDB (http://www.mongodb.org/). It sports a javascript shell and objects that are natively represented in JSON (BSON technically).

The server supports indexing and other things that give you the warm SQL fuzzies.

Answer (score 0):

What about [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/)? It uses JSON notation to store the objects and you could access the db directly from the client side via its REST interface.

Besides, there are already several jquery plugins for CouchDB, [jqCouch](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqcouch) just to mention one.